# Как отобразить содержимое .msg файла?

Tags: android

Есть .msg файл, который находится в папке assets. Как отобразить его содержимое на активности?

Comment: Что за .msg файл? Чем сгенерирован, Microsoft Outlook что ли ?

Comment: @pavlofff да, именно.

Comment: Для отображения файлов Microsoft Outlook нужна отдельная программа, в своей активии его не открыть. Вы можете вызывать неявный интент, как [в ответе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/473068/177345) ниже и файл из вашей программы откроется в той, которая сможет его отобразить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я открываю таким образом:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
String type = "application/msword";
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(path)), type);
    try {
       startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
       showShortMessage(getString(R.string.need_doc_reader)); 
    }
```

Но, разумеется, должен стоять MS office на девайсе, чтобы сработало.